# Invalid API key: You must be granted a valid key tmdb laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

i am trying to install `php-tmdb/laravel` on my laravel 5.5 but getting error on basic test

> Invalid API key: You must be granted a valid key

i try with google and found this link https://github.com/php-tmdb/laravel/issues/38

but its not working or can't understand

help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

auto discovery in this package is not working correctly

just add this on providers

> config/app.php

```
Tmdb\Laravel\TmdbServiceProvider::class,
```

everything is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

According to the github README.md https://github.com/php-tmdb/laravel

After you install the package, run this command to publish the configuration file:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tmdb\Laravel\TmdbServiceProviderLaravel5"
```

then edit this file: `config/tmdb.php` in your application with your api key.

The configuration file should look like this:
https://github.com/php-tmdb/laravel/blob/master/src/config/tmdb.php

Notice `'api_key' => '',` fill this in and then re-run your code/test.

Here's where you get your API key from: https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started

After changing the config, for good measure; clear your config cache with this command:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

edit `/vendor/php-tmdb/laravel/src/config/tmdb.php`

find `'api_key' => '',` and add your key here.